# XML deserialization cannot resolve attribute type

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api2, xml-deserialization

I am working on a project where I communicate with an API service through both REST and Comet semantics.

### XML

So, the problem at hand.
I receive this error when I try to deserialize the following XML.

> Error at resolve type "xsi:SubscriptionEvent"
>   NetBike.Xml.TypeResolvers.XmlTypeResolveException

Note: I use NetBike, but the error exist in the default xml formatter too

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsi:Event
xsi1:type="xsi:SubscriptionEvent"
xmlns:xsi="http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi"
xmlns:xsi1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsi:eventID>0787e727-e73d-43e0-a7b1-e968ba72ea53</xsi:eventID>
<xsi:sequenceNumber>1</xsi:sequenceNumber>
<xsi:userId>11111111@voip.company.domain</xsi:userId>
<xsi:externalApplicationId>NewClient</xsi:externalApplicationId>
<xsi:subscriptionId>24def51b-21fb-4d60-a1ef-67477dcafcfb</xsi:subscriptionId>
<xsi:channelId>575cfe44-2cc7-4cf5-bc05-bcc462bcbb02</xsi:channelId>
<xsi:targetId>22222222@voip.company.domain</xsi:targetId>
<xsi:eventData xsi1:type="xsi:ACDSubscriptionEvent"/>
</xsi:Event>
```

I'm not a XML "Jedi knight", but I know the basics.
The errors tells me I have a problem with the type xsi1:type="xsi:SubscriptionEvent" this is the attribute on the root xml (Event) element, this is the three attributes in question.

```
xsi1:type="xsi:SubscriptionEvent"
xmlns:xsi="http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi"
xmlns:xsi1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

---

### C# Class

I am using C#, until now I have had no problems creating equivalent classes based on the XML returned to me upon development.
If I take out the "bad data" the exception is avoided.

*Event Class* (I'm using this in Web API V2 environment, so technically its a model)

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Event", Namespace = "http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi")]
public class Event
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "eventID", Namespace = "http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi")]
    public string EventID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sequenceNumber", Namespace = "http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi")]
    public string SequenceNumber { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "userId", Namespace = "http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "externalApplicationId", Namespace = "http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi")]
    public string ExternalApplicationId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "subscriptionId", Namespace = "http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi")]
    public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "channelId", Namespace = "http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi")]
    public string ChannelId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "targetId", Namespace = "http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi")]
    public string TargetId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "eventData", Namespace = "http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi")]
    public EventData eventData { get; set; }


    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string xsi { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi1", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsi1 { get; set; }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "eventData", Namespace = "http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi")]
    public class EventData
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This class was mainly generated from http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/
(that greatly speeds up this otherwise dull task)

---

### Valid XML?

When I run the XML through different XML validators, I get different responses, some validates the XML fine, and some don't.

- http://www.xmlvalidation.com: Fail
- http://www.validome.org/xml/validate: Fail
- http://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidate: Ok

To me, I find it hard to comprehend how exactly the structure is supposed to work.
It seems like the type attribute should be built upon the xsi1 attribute, but everything I have tried have failed.

My last resort will be to read the response as a string, then strip off the annoying XML so that it can be deserialized properly.

Best regards.
A slightly frustrated developer in dire need of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the confusion has arisen because `xsi:type` is part of XML schema and defines the types of various elements.  You're trying to treat it as a normal attribute, and the serialiser is trying to use it to determine what objects to map the data to.  The objects it's looking for aren't defined in the model.

Essentially, you need to model your classes after the type hierarchy your XML implies.  So you have a base `Event` class with a `SubscriptionEvent` sub-class, and you have a base `EventData` class with a `ACDSubscriptionEvent` sub-class.

Note that (at least for `XmlSerializer`), you can omit a lot of your namespaces as they're inherited from the parent.  You probably know more about the hierarchy than I do, so some of the properties may be able to be moved into the base class etc.  Ideally, you'd have the XML schema file (.xsd) and would be able to generate the classes using `xsd.exe`, but this will work for the given XML:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(SubscriptionEvent))]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi")]
public abstract class Event
{

}

[XmlType(Namespace = "http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi")]
public class SubscriptionEvent : Event
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "eventID")]
    public string EventID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sequenceNumber")]
    public string SequenceNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "userId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "externalApplicationId")]
    public string ExternalApplicationId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "subscriptionId")]
    public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "channelId")]
    public string ChannelId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "targetId")]
    public string TargetId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "eventData")]
    public EventData EventData { get; set; }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(ACDSubscriptionEvent))]
public abstract class EventData
{

}

[XmlType(Namespace = "http://schema.broadsoft.com/xsi")]
public class ACDSubscriptionEvent : EventData
{

}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dmMZJ6) for a working demo (using `XmlSerializer`).

Comment: This solves my problem! I owe you a huge thanks, although there seems to be another issue that might have contributed to my headache. I used XmlFormatters (because it is Web API) and they can not deserialize using your improved class I'm afraid. Good thing you did a fiddle, that did let me see past that limitation. A huge thanks from me.